# how to save a changed layout android?

Tags: android, android-layout

so I have this layout with an imageView. The users changes the image of the imageView(that happens in another activity, I pass the image path with an intent to this activity), then I want to save the layout. Later on, I want to call that layout with the changed ImageView, I can't figure it out! Can someone help me?!?

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    ImagePath = getIntent().getStringExtra("imagePath");
    setContentView(R.layout.item);
    ImageView v = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.maxCard);
    v.setImageBitmap(BitmapUtility.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(ImagePath,500,500));
   //Now I want to save this layout!!! BUt i don't know how?!?

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);//My second layout
    al = new ArrayList<>();
    al.add("max");
    al.add("launcher");
    al.add("php");
    al.add("c");
    al.add("python");
    al.add("java");
    al.add("html");
    al.add("c++");
    al.add("css");
    al.add("javascript");
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.item, R.id.helloText, al);//HERE I WANT TO USE that changed layout by the user...
    flingContainer.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Comment: Maybe you can save your image name in shared preferences in a string then use an if statement to check your image name in your shared preferences then set it. Add this code in your onResume.

Comment: @HusseinElFeky But I don't think its a matter of putting the string in the preferences, it's more about how to save the changed layout x_x

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't save a layout in android, but you can achieve what you want by using shared preferences or something similar. Like for example, save your image everytime you change it in shared preferences, then in onResume, load that image.

Comment: @HusseinElFeky wait can you give an example for this? Because I'm not seeing how saving the string will do anything?

Comment: save the image path to shared preferences and set the `ImagePath` variable to the path obtained from shared prefs

Comment: @akash93 I don't see how that changes anything? Because if I save the image path in sharedPreferences, i still need to set the ImageView in the item layout to that image. AND then change to another layout, and then call on that layout with the image changed, moving the string path won't help me, or at least i dont see how it can.

Comment: You don't want to change the layout, you want to change the data that is displayed in some view in your layout. Changing a layout would mean changing e.g. an ImageView to a TextView. You don't want that, you want to change one image for another, NOT THE VIEW.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `onResume()` instead of `ImagePath = getIntent().getStringExtra("imagePath");` do `ImagePath = prefs.getString("image_path_key","default_image_path");` and in your other activity instead of passing the image path in the intent save it with the same `SharedPreferences` key.